# Django template dynamic URL

Tags: django, dynamic, django-templates, href

Suppose I have a set of templates that are using a block of HTML repeatedly.  I would like to put the reused HTML into an `{% include %}` or `{% block reused-stuff %}` but one of the HTML tags is an `href` that I can't seem to dynamically generate.  (This is similar to the breadcrumb problem.)

Here is an example of the repeated HTML:

```
<td><a href="{% url analytics:buyer-stats:brand client.slug %}">{{ row.brand }}</a></td>
<td>{{ row.num_leads }}</td>
<td>{{ row.num_sold }}</td>
<td>{{ row.revenue }}</td>
<td>{{ row.scrub_rate|default_if_none:"N/A" }}</td>
```

Notice the first `<td>` includes the `href` to `analytics:buyer-stats:brand`.  I need to dynamically change that value to be several other values (depending on the template using this include or block).  i.e. `analytics:buyer-stats:offer`, `analytics:buyer-stats:client`, etc.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this on the template side?  It's easy enough to pass in the `row` object using `with row=my_data`, but how can I pass the url value?

EDIT:
This project is using Django 1.4 and Python 2.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is not valid in Django 1.5, and for this very reason. You must now either use a variable, or a literal string surrounded with quotes, for the url name. That makes it easy to do what you like: define a context variable for the view name, and use that in the url tag.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.4.  Is is possible to do this in 1.4?

Comment: You can use `{% load url from future %}` at the top of the template to turn this on. Note it will change the behaviour for all url tags in that template.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I haven't chosen your answer as a solution because I haven't had the time to verify this will work for my situation.  Thank you for the suggestion.  I will upvote your comment.